# How do i change the font of a specific layer in adobe photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts

I have a photoshop psd file, with a font.

I want to replace the particular font of a particular layer with a different font.

I have the different font downloaded and installed on my windows machine.

What do i do to change the font of the particular layer?

Comment: You could of Googled this question...

Comment: @SaturnsEye i tried, i didn't see much that made sense. I've never used photoshop before, i'm just putting the images a designer made for me into an app, and wanted to change the font used to a font i could legally use. Sorry if it is a basic question, but photoshop is *hard*.

Comment: I can understand from a beginners point of view that Photoshop can look intimidating but once you only need to use about 5% of it to do most basic things you'll start to breeze through it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you even *tried* searching for this on Google?  I mean, I don't want to sound rude, but this is **extremely** basic stuff!

Select the font layer that you want to change and (wait for it...) change it.

If you're like me (I'm just going to assume that you aren't, but if you are) and you have the Character menu in your tool bar on the right, just click that.

[image: toolbar]

Otherwise go here:

[image: menu]

Which brings up this box:

[image: character]

Comment: that looks easy, but when i do that nothing changes. do i have to... save it somehow? I am definitely selecting the text, and the text is definitely text.

Comment: I have no idea what's going on, on your side, or why it isn't working; this should be a pretty straight-forward alteration.  Can you provide some screen shots in your original question, so I can see what your issue is?

Comment: so i guess i don't know how to select the image? i think the text is somehow embedded in the layer itself?

Comment: is it possible i need to "unlayer" the layer to get to the text?

Comment: @bharal It sounds a lot to me like the text layer is actually rasterized and not editable.  Does the layer look like mine does in the first image I shared, meaning does it have that big T inside the box?  If not, there is no way you can change it and you will need to retype it.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually much simpler to do it this way:

Make your text.
[image: Add Text]
Highlight your text with the text tool (like in word).
[image: Highlight it]
Click on font style up top.
[image: Choose your style]

After that, remember to save your psd file, and your done.